# Does this question on topology contain a typo?

Tags: general-topology

Some classmates and I think this question our textbook contains a typo that makes it unsolvable.

> Consider $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Find a nonempty set $A$ different from $\Bbb R$ such that the closure of $A$ intersect the closure of $A$ complement is equal to the empty set.

EDIT: As clarified in comments, the phrase *the closure of $A$ intersect the closure of $A$ complement is equal to the empty set.* means $\overline{A}\cap \overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}=\varnothing$ or, equivalently, $\overline{A}\cap (\overline{\complement{A}})=\varnothing$.

Thoughts? Is this question unsolvable?

Comment: Do you mean
$$\overline{A}\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\overline{A})=\varnothing$$
or do you mean
$$\overline{A}\cap \overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}=\varnothing$$

Comment: Neither. The closure of A intersect the closure of A complement. Where A is different from R.

Comment: That's still not clear. [Learn how to use MathJax here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/184154). If it's neither of the above, do you mean
$$\overline{A\cap \overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}}=\varnothing$$

Comment: \overline{A}\cap (\overline\complement{A})=\varnothing

Where A is different from R.


^Hmm. It's not coming out as expected. Let me see if I can fix it. In the mean time, here is a shot at being more explicit: you have the closure of A. Then you have the closure of A complement. The intersection of these two must equal the empty set. And A must be different than R.

Comment: I think the complement of $A$ is the same as $\mathbb R\setminus A$, so the second line of curious's comment should be what you want.

Comment: Hmm, then I am not sure. I don't think those formulations are correct. If we insist on using set difference, then I think the left-hand side of the intersection should read A - R with a bar on top. And the right-hand side of the intersection should be enclosed with parentheses and a superscript for the complement should be added to that quantity. And then all of it (the RHS) should be beneath the bar!

Comment: Is that what you want: $\overline{A}\cap (\overline{\complement{A}})=\varnothing $?

Comment: Where that big C is the complement, yes. And then we would parenthetically add that A must not be R (but I would not use set difference for that).

Comment: @Brian If you put your markup between a pair of dollar signs it will render properly.

Comment: @Brian: Set difference is preferable: complement depends on context (and is not always well-defined), while set difference does not.

Comment: @Brian I have added to your post mathematical expressions suggested in comments (which you have said are correct interpretation of your question) as this improves readability. Please, edit your question further if you prefer different wording or any other changes are needed.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: If you are _really_ interested in whether there is a typo, you should perhaps add what text (and where in said text) this is from.

Answer (score 1):

It implies that $\mathbb R$ is disconnected, so it's impossible to find such an $A$.